# fatal error: 'google/protobuf/port_def.inc' file not found

Tags: c++

I am using CLion cmakelist.txt to compile but receive the following error. The program compiled with g++ but somehow lacks dependency when I am using cmake. anyone know how to solve this?

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
    project(CTCWordBeamSearch_master)
    find_package(PkgConfig)
    pkg_check_modules(TensorFlow REQUIRED tensorflow)
    link_directories(${TensorFlow_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    include_directories(${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_compile_definitions(${TensorFlow_CFLAGS_OTHER})
    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
    find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    include_directories(.)
    include_directories(cpp)
    include_directories(cpp/proj)
    include_directories(cpp/src)
    include_directories(cpp/src/pybind)
    include_directories(cpp/src/pybind/pybind11)
    include_directories(cpp/src/pybind/pybind11/detail)
    include_directories(cpp/src/utfcpp)
    include_directories(cpp/src/utfcpp/utf8)
    include_directories(data)
    include_directories(doc)
    include_directories(np)
    include_directories(py)
    include_directories(tf)
    
    add_executable(CTCWordBeamSearch_master
           ...
           )
    target_link_libraries(CTCWordBeamSearch_master ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(CTCWordBeamSearch_master ${TensorFlow_LIBRARIES})
```